# Informações Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Gostaria de saber o seguinte... tenho algumas imagens de mapas, que indicam uma determinada cobertura, eu gostaria de adicionar essas imagens por cima do google mapas...  acredito que isso não seja difícil...  O grande problema que vejo, é que essas imagens possuem uma densidade.

Quando mais escuro o roxo,  digamos, taxa de homicidio - ex:100, dai quanto mais claro, Homicidio - ex: 10...  e assim por diante.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim, eu não sei como é feito no google mapas. Imaginem que ao clicar no mapa ele terá que me informar dados.

Como que isso é feito no google mapas, eu adiciono a imagem, ou terei que criar com a API do google mapas?  Possuem algum exemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal seria você utilizar recursos do próprio Google Maps e desenhar as regiões em vez de colocar uma imagem dentro.

Criei no [JSFiddle um exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/h4ay3yko/1/).

Basicamente você define as coordenadas da região que será desenhado o local.

**Exemplo da parte importante:**

```
var homicidioCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-9.86062814536589, -50.25146484375),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-9.384032109601689, -56.75537109375),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-12.876069959946493, -57.041015625),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-14.477234210156507, -54.0087890625),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-13.26133317079826, -50.64697265625),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-9.86062814536589, -50.25146484375),
];

// Constrói o desenho.
areaAfetada = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: homicidioCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
});
```

**A saída:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com isso você pode ir criando as regiões e inserindo as cores como bem entender. Coloquei também um evento para ao clicar com o botão direito do mouse mostrar a latitude e longitude do local. A melhor forma ainda seria você realizar o desenho todo no mapa, e salvar as coordenadas.

Como eu disse, o exemplo está no [JSFiddle um exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/h4ay3yko/1/).
Referências: [polygon-simple](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple?hl=pt-br)

Comment: obrigado é  isso mesmo que buscava,terei mesmo que desenha os mapas. Para finaliar você  conhece algum programa ou site, onde eu possa estar upando a imagem e clicar por cima do pontos e ele retorna o JS das coordenadas?

Comment: @abcd desconheço

Comment: Vasculhei bem, encontrei alguns... Polygon Creator Class, só modificar... ATT

Answer (score 0):

Minha sugestão crie caches das imagens utilizando o Maptiler e depois utilize o Overlaying an image map type da própria API do Google Maps

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay?hl=pt-br

Poste suas dúvidas também na comunidade do Google Maps API Brasil https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102409361642970934842